# using apply template within javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I'm trying to create a html page which shows personell on google maps. To create the different markers on the map, i have a javascript that creates a marker for each entry in the array locations. This array is supposed to be filled with data coming from the db (in xml) and has to be transformed into my html.

Please take a look in my xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var infos = [];
        var locations = [
            <xsl:apply-templates select='//rows'/>
        ];
        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.59, 4.35),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("default"),myOptions);
            setMarkers(map,locations)
            }
        function setMarkers(map,locations){
            var marker, i
            for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
            {   var name = locations[i][0]
                var long = locations[i][1]
                var lat = locations[i][2]
                var contentmarker =  locations[i][3]
                latlngset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, title: name , position: latlngset
                });
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition())
                var content = contentmarker
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow()
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click', (function(marker,content,infowindow){ 
                    return function() {
                    /* close the previous info-window */
                    closeInfos();
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                            infowindow.open(map,marker);
                            /* keep the handle, in order to close it on next click event */
                            infos[0]=infowindow;
                    };
                })(marker,content,infowindow)); 
            }
        }
        function closeInfos(){
            if(infos.length &gt; 0){
                /* detach the info-window from the marker ... undocumented in the API docs */
                infos[0].set("marker", null);
                /* and close it */
                infos[0].close();
                /* blank the array */
                infos.length = 0;
            }
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="default" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match='rows'>
<xsl:for-each-group select='row' group-by='@SiteNr'>
    [&apos;<xsl:value-of select='@SiteName'/>&apos;, &apos;<xsl:value-of select='@LON_R'/>&apos;, &apos;<xsl:value-of select='@LAT_R'/>
    &apos;, &apos;&lt;b&gt;<xsl:value-of select='@RegionName'/>&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;Details (<xsl:value-of select='@SiteNr'/>):
    <table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>PersNr</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>DeptNr</th>
            <th>DeptName</th>
            <th>PostNr</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@PersNr"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@FirstName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@DeptCode"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@DeptName"/></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@PostNr"/></td>
                </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='5'>TOTAAL</td>
            <td align='center'><xsl:value-of select="(count(current-group()/@PersNr))"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>&apos;] 
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If i try CDATA around the script, it runs, but my script tags are transformed with < and > and the script doens't work anymore.

Extract of my xml:

```
<rows>
    <row PersNr="B15975" Name="Vandendriessche" Firstname="Rudolf" DeptCode"J20100" DeptName="HR" Post="1230" RegionNum="3" RegionName="Plateau Berlaar" SiteNum="11002D" SiteName="KW BELGIELEI" LON_kw="4.418" LAT_kw="51.205" />
```

I'm new to XSL/HTML/JAVASCRIPT so if you know the answer, please help me, with some extra information (if you can provide it).

Comment: Could you show a bit more of your XSLT rather than just truncating it in the middle (in particular the template that matches **rows** and the javascript following the xsl:apply-templates). Also, showing your input XML may help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For a start you need to replace this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1tbIAqN0XqcgTR1-FxYoVTVq6Is6lD98&amp;sensor=false"></script>
```

In particular, notice how the `&` needs to be escaped as `&amp;`

With respect getting your javascript to work after it has been built, you could manually escape all the problematic characters. In your case, that means replacing this line

```
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
```

With this line

```
for (i = 0; i &lt; locations.length; i++)
```

This is to stop the XML parser treating the `<` as the start of a tag.

Alternatively, you can wrap the text as CDATA, but you will need to do it in two places. Before the **xsl:apply-templates** and after. For example, you could do this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <![CDATA[
    var infos = [];
    var locations = [
  ]]>
  <xsl:apply-templates select='//rows'/>
  <![CDATA[
    ];
    function initialize() {
    }
  ]]>
 </script>
```

Comment: If I change the problematic characters inside my script the <xsl:apply-templates> isn't recognized as XSL and doensn't work. In order to let the apply-templates to be recognized, i have to change the < and >  around the tag scripts. But this gives the same result as when using CDATA, see below.

I tried wrapping the text as CDATA but when it transforms to html, the tags for script are changed to &lt; and &gt; and the browser doesn't know what to do with it and just displays it as text instead of recognizing it as a script.